# UILabel's text will not change

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uilabel, ibaction

Hey guys i am creating a UILabel and a UIButton programatically inside another button, so when this button is pressed, it creates a UILabel and a UIButton and adds is as a subview on a seperate page. I want a button to be able to add 1 to the labels value. Here is the code for the button that adds the label to the second view:

```
-(IBAction)outlet1:(id)sender{
UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addButton1:)    
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[addButton setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
addButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 35, 40.0);
[cart.view addSubview:addButton];

UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(137, 150, 25, 35)];
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
label.text = @"1";
[cart.view addSubview:label];
}
```

and this is the button i want to be able to alter the label:

```
- (void)addButton1:(id)sender {
[black.label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[black.label.text intValue] +1]];    
}
```

`black` is an ivar that is associated with the first viewController and `cart` is assoctiated with the second viewController!My problem is when i press the button that is hooked up with the `addButton1:` method, it crashes? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Could you tell us the crash message you get on the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init your `UILabel` in `viewDidLoad` and create an **ivar** to it, then you can access it throughout your `@implementation`.

```
@synthesize label;

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(137, 150, 25, 35)];
}
```

Comment: ok i tried this. I tried initializing the label in the `viewDidLoad` of the second viewConroller and it doesnt show up now? I have created the ivar in the firstVC and i want to display it in the second VC so how could i do this?

Comment: Well, you also need to add the rest of the code for you label, specifically the `[cart.view addSubview:addButton];`, otherwise, you are just creating a label and not adding it's view to anything.

Comment: i have done this both for the button and for the label? I believe i added it to the question. and thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: You can't use a single label or ivar in more than 1 controller. You will need to create a label for each Controller you have, then you can pass information to these labels, but you cannot add the label from view 1 to view 2.

Comment: oh ok how do you recommend i do this?? Im stumped! will it appear as if there is only 1 label to the user though? Thanks

Comment: As long as you create the ivars to these labels, you can send properties to them from other classes, and as long as you have an active connection to the 2nd controller.

Comment: oh god... i have no idea how to do this? sorry for the inconvenience! i know how to create ivars! but im not sure on how to send the properties from other classes and what do you mean my have an "active connection to the second controller"??

Comment: `MyController * controller = [[MyController alloc] init];` then you can send `[controller.label setText:@"Something"];`

Comment: oh i tried doing something like this already! its in my question and its inside the method `addbutton1:` could this work?

Comment: I dont know what **black** is.

Comment: it says right under the code box thingy that black is a variable associated with the first VC so i put
`BlackFacePlatesViewController * black = [[...]];`

Comment: What is the output of the crash?

Comment: These are the normal words, there were a bunch of numbers below this but i didnt think you needed to see them. 
it is:   2011-09-08 20:28:00.757 FacePlates[3165:b303] -[BlackFacePlateViewControlller addButton1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e11a00
2011-09-08 20:28:00.762 FacePlates[3165:b303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BlackFacePlateViewControlller addButton1:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e11a00'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: is outlet1 and addButton1 in the same controller? It is crashing becuase addButton1 doesnt exist in the controller you are trying to call it from.

Comment: OH i got it!! Thanks i had to put the two methods in the same file!! :D Thank you thank you!!! :)